# VBA Replace Only leading and trailing line breaks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text as follows stored in a variable `myStringVariable`:

```
"


    About this item 
    This fits your . 
    Make sure this fits by entering your model number. 

"
```

Sorry I had to use `""` above to display the leading and lagging line breaks I have in my cells which are generated though VBA macro.

How do I get rid of leading and lagging line breaks to get the following:

```
    About this item 
    This fits your . 
    Make sure this fits by entering your model number.
```

I am not sure how to approach this.

Edit:

```
Replace(myStringVariable, vbNewLine, "")
```

will replace all line breaks. So, I need a `Trim` function kind of solution I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `trimCHAR` function that works similarly to Excel's `TRIM` function, except you can specify the character to be TRIM'd.

It will remove all leading and trailing `char`, as well as any *doubled* `char` within the string (leaving a single `char` within the string, as `TRIM` does with spaces)

```
Function trimCHAR(ByVal S As String, char As String)
'similar to worksheet TRIM function except can specify character(s) to TRIM
  Dim RE As Object
  Dim I As Long

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .multiLine = True

'need to do separately, otherwise multiple chars within will
'be removed
        .Pattern = char & "*$"
        S = .Replace(S, "") 'Remove extra chars at end of string
        .Pattern = char & "*([^" & char & "]" & char & ")*"
        S = .Replace(S, "$1") 'Remove extra chars at start of string or within
End With
trimCHAR = S

End Function
```

**Original**

[image]

Usage on worksheet: `=trimCHAR(cell_ref,CHAR(10))`

*in a macro, you might use `=trimChar(myStringVariable, vblf)`*

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Great answer!  `trimCHAR()` is new to me.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks, Gary. I wrote it to mimic a similar function in Power Query. This question encouraged me to finish it, which I just did with last edit.

Comment: Thanks......sadly, I cannot up-vote more than once.

Answer (score 2):

The following function will replace all leading and trailing newline and carriage returns. If you want, add more characters (eg space and Tabs) to the check.

```
Function TrimNewline(s As String) As String
     
    Dim i As Long, firstchar As Long, lastChar As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        Dim c As String
        c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If c <> vbCr And c <> vbLf Then
            If firstchar = 0 Then
                firstchar = i
            Else
                lastChar = i
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    TrimNewline = Mid(s, firstchar, lastChar - firstchar + 1)

End Function
```

A test:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String
    s = vbCrLf & vbLf & vbCr & "(AAAAA" & vbCrLf & "BBB)" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Debug.Print "<" & TrimNewline(s) & ">"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub GiveMeABreak()
    Dim c As String, cell As Range, s As String
    
    c = Chr(10)
    For Each cell In Selection
        s = cell.Value
        If Left(s, 1) = c Then
            s = Mid(s, 2)
        End If
        If Right(s, 1) = c Then
            s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
        End If
        cell.Value = s
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

Only the leading and trailing characters are tested.  If there are multiple leading linebreaks, only the first will be removed.

**EDIT#1:**

This version of the code will remove **all** leading and trailing linebreaks:

```
Sub GiveMeABreak2()
    Dim c As String, cell As Range, s As String
    
    c = Chr(10)
    For Each cell In Selection
        s = cell.Value
        While Left(s, 1) = c
            s = Mid(s, 2)
        Wend
        While Right(s, 1) = c
            s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
        Wend
        cell.Value = s
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @Zanam  Then modify my logic to process your text before your macro fills the cells.

Comment: looks like I have multiple newLine character at beginning and end

Comment: yeah I read your code and I can modify the code, to make it work only in macro. Thanks for that part.

Comment: @Zanam  see my **Note**

Comment: I am good with your code except this part: only the first will be removed. I see you have 91k reputation, so removing multiple leading linebreaks is not feasible?

Comment: @Zanam  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score 1):

The following function may be of interest:

```
Function CleanTrim(ByVal Text As String, Optional ConvertNonBreakingSpace As Boolean = True) As String
    ' https://excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/155-Trim-all-Cells-in-a-Worksheet-VBA#post1092
    ' Code modified from that by Rick Rothstein
    Dim i As Long, CodesToClean As Variant
    CodesToClean = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, _
                         21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 127, 129, 141, 143, 144, 157)
    If ConvertNonBreakingSpace Then Text = Replace(Text, Chr(160), " ")
    For i = LBound(CodesToClean) To UBound(CodesToClean)
        If InStr(Text, Chr(CodesToClean(i))) Then Text = Replace(Text, Chr(CodesToClean(i)), "")
    Next i
    CleanTrim = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Text)
End Function
```